# How can I search for multiple specific keys with specific values in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary in my Python code:

```
LOCATIONS = {
    1: {
        "Name": "West of house",
        "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0,
    },
    2: {
        "Name": "Test Location",
        "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0,
    }
}
```

How can I check the current values of x, y, and z and match them to a location and get its name?

Comment: Rethink your container and use a dictionary with a tuple of the coordinates as key. This will be **much** more efficient

Comment: Use a loop that checks whether `x, y, z` contain the searched values.

Comment: Not sure I understood the question, are you asking how to access a value in a dictionary?

Comment: what do the keys 1 and 2 represent? would it not make more sense having a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?:

```
name = None
for values in LOCATIONS.values():
    if (values["x"], values["y"], values["z"]) == (0, 0, 0):
        name = values["Name"]
```

Keep in mind that if there are multiple names, that have the same x, y & z then the last one will be the output. If you want all of them then you should store them in a container like a list.